# Logitech Z-5 Speakers

Tags: speakers, logitech

I have a set of USB Logitech Z-5 Speakers and they do Not Work with Ubuntu 12.04LTS, yet they work with Fedora 19. What's up with that?

I hope somebody can help to get them to work as I prefer Ubuntu to Fedora 19. I checked the CD which came with them and there's only a Driver for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 19 uses a newer kernel (3.10). Please try to install and boot `linux-image-generic-lts-raring`, which will install the raring kernel (3.8).

If that does not work try the latest [mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).